# How can I do Google drive data migration?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I am trying to do drive data migration from one user to another using https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/data-transfer/v1/reference/transfers/insert

Code Block:

```
{
  "newOwnerUserId": "new user id",
  "oldOwnerUserId": "old user id",
  "applicationDataTransfers": [
    {
      "applicationId": 122344
    }
  ]
}
```

I am getting 200 response but I don't see any new folder in `newOwnerUserId` with `oldOwnerUser` Data.

Can somebody please suggest what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Define Privacy level otherwise it will not work